# In visual studio 2015 ,Can i make a software/App which can run on any devices and any operating systems?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015, atom-editor, apache-cordova

I have knowledge in Asp.net technology and recently i have just completed a Universal windows platform app which run on any windows-10 device.But now i want to a make  software which can run on any devices (Desktop/Tabulate/Mobile and all.) and any of the operating system (ios,android,Windows).

My question is that ,Is Microsoft provide ant feature in visual studio so i can make a software in visual studio which will run on each and every devices and operating system.

I just recently read a blog of Apache Cordova ,Visual studio code and also read about angular.js and node.js and react.

I also hear about Atom editor so any one please guide me and suggest a better way to start a new application.

Comment: Welcome to programming, where there are too many platforms and architectures to count and every programming language targets a subset of them. This is unfortunately a huge and broad question with even huger and broader potential answers :/ If you want to see what I mean, write a console application in C++ that works on Linux, OS/X and Windows and then try porting it to Arduino or Rasp Pi. You'll quickly understand the brevity of the question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be available in the future. It's not only something can run on Desktop/Tablet/Mobile. The important is which Operating System where the application can be run. Now we can use C# for Universal App run on Windows, or Xamarin for native mobile app run on iOS, Android and so on. But we cannot use C# for building application run on Ubuntu and MacOS.
Currently, there is no super language as your expectation. But if you want to make a jump start for your idea which can be run on a lot of devices, you can take a look at below technol

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) - Compatible with Mac, Windows, and Linux, Electron apps build and run on three platforms with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

[Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) - Xamarin apps are built with standard, native user interface controls using C# on iOS, Android, Mac.

[Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) - Mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JS. Target multiple platforms with one code base. Support iOS, Android, Windows Phone and so on.

[Native Script](https://www.nativescript.org/) - NativeScript is a runtime that lets you build native iOS, Android using JavaScript code.